# How do I find the transformation matrix given the following bases?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a set $N$ let $id_N: N \to N$ be the identity function. Let $V := \mathbb{R}[t]_{\leq d}$. What is the Transformation Matrix $X := M_{B}^A(id_V)$ of $id_V$ with respect to the bases $A := \{1, t-\alpha, \cdots, (t-\alpha)^d\}$ and $B := \{1, t, \cdots, t^d\}$

Any advice on where to start?

Comment: Can you explain what this $M_B^A(\operatorname{id}_V)$ means? Possibly answer your question.

Comment: From my lecture notes as I understood it, this is just a shorthand notation, which means the matrix representation of $id_V$ with respect to the bases A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is my advice
Let $A=\lbrace 1,(t-\alpha),(t-\alpha)^2, \cdots (t-\alpha)^d \rbrace$ and  $B=\lbrace 1,t, \cdots t^d \rbrace$.
Consider $idv(1), idv(t-\alpha),idv((t-\alpha)^2),...idv((t-\alpha)^d)$ and then the results that evaluate $idv$  in each element of the Basis A, you need writte these results like a linear combination of elements of B. and take the coeficients and finally these coeficients are the coeficients of the matrix representation of the $idv$ in the basis A and B.

Comment: Thank you, this was just the bit of explanation I needed to solve the exercise.